# How to auto increment a string with sql query

Tags: mysql

I am stuck at a point where i have to increment a string, and my strings are of type `C001`,`SC001`,`B001`

in my data base they are defined like

[image: This is the data into my db]

what i am trying to do do is write a query which check the previous highest code present into my db and the incriment it to +1

- for example `C001` -> `C002,`C009`->C010,`C099`->C100 and so on
- Similarly for `SC001`->`SC002`,`SC009`->`SC010`,`SC099`->SC100 and so on
- Similarly fro `B001` -> `B002,`B009`->B010,`B099`->B100 and so on

I have a query which my friend has suggested me to use but that query only incriminating `AAAA`->`AAAA01` , `AAAA09`->`AAAA10`

query is

```
    SELECT id AS PrevID, CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(id, 1, 4),
    IF(CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) <= 9, '0', ''),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) + 1
) AS NextID
FROM (
    -- since you allow strings such as AAAA20 and AAAA100 you can no longer use MAX
    SELECT id
    FROM t
    ORDER BY SUBSTRING(id, 1, 4) DESC, CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) x
```

when i am replacing ID with CategoryCode it is giving me `PrevID-C004` `NextID-C00401` which is not my requirement i want  `PrevID-C004` and `NextID->C005`

**NOTE** i am using my sqlServer 5.1

Comment: You can't easily do this on MySQL 5.x.  Question: What happens when a record, e.g. `C003`, gets deleted?  Do you recycle that ID?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no scoop currently for deletion i just have to add new row and the above query i have posted i am using mysql 5x only

Comment: @viveksingh if the record goes more than hundreds then it will be static as sc999

Comment: @Aishwarya this one is never gona happen because.it can go max to max 300-400

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design - a confusion about the kind of information the database needs in order to relate one piece of data to another , and the kind of thing you want to present to an end user.

Comment: Which database are you actually using? You've tagged my-sql but mentioned sql-server in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this one ,

```
SELECT 
CategoryCode,CAST(CONCAT(LPAD(CategoryCode,1,0),LPAD(MAX(RIGHT(CategoryCode, 
3)) + 1, 3, 0) ) AS CHAR),
FROM  test

SELECT 
SubCategoryCode,CAST(CONCAT(LPAD(SubCategoryCode,2,0), 
LPAD(MAX(RIGHT(CategoryCode, 3)) + 1, 3, 0) ) AS CHAR), 
FROM  test

SELECT  
BrandCode,CAST(CONCAT(LPAD(BrandCode,1,0), LPAD(MAX(RIGHT(BrandCode, 3)) + 
1, 3, 0))  AS CHAR) FROM  test
```

Comment: hey you are doing it in one query only.it is giving fine result..but i have to write 3 separate query for that.as i have to use all three separately